# display old label style in new R leaflet 2.0

Tags: r, leaflet

The R leaflet labels have changed in the latest release 2.0 and now have a solid white background without a border.   Is there a way to print a label that's similar to the [old style](https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-labels) without installing an old version?

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(
    lng=-118.456554, lat=34.078039,
    label='My label',
    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something similar by overriding the css, place the following code in your own CSS that is called after leaflet.css

```
.leaflet-tooltip{
    border:4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

You can play with the values to make it look any way you want, this goes for pretty much any element in leaflet, like the popups.

Comment: Thanks, adding that as a style to `labelOptions` works too with `style = list("border" = "4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)", "background-color" = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)")))`.   It's close enough for now.